# Is there any way I can simplify this regular expression (for removing prefixes)

Tags: regex

The expression I have now is

```
/^((\d{1,2}(?!\d)(\.|-)\d{2}(?!\d)\s?)|(\d{1,3}(?!\d)\.?\s?))(-\s)?/
```

Its purpose is to match (for replacement with blank) any numeric prefix along the lines of

```
"01. "
"01. - "
"01."
"01 - "
"01"
"0.01"
```

And various other combinations.

So far it's working for the cases I've come across, but I'm wondering if there's any way to condense it.

Comment: What are they prefixes on?  Could you get away with, for instance, stripping everything up until the first word character?

Comment: More information is needed, such as actual sample data values. We don't know what *various other combinations* might be, or what exactly is being *prefixed*. There could be many ways to do this better or with an improved regex, but you've not provided the information needed to determine that in your question. Also, clarify your requirement - you say you want to replace *any numeric prefix*, but include prefixes that are *not* numeric, such as "01 -" and "01.-". (And are the quotes part of the prefix, or just meaningless noise in your samples?)

Comment: And what about other numbers that come after the *prefix*? How do you define where the *prefix* ends and the non-prefix begins? Your question is unanswerable without much more specific requirements.

Comment: The quotes are there because some of the examples have tailing whitespace, which I would be removing with the regex.  The quotes aren't in the actual files.  As for where it ends, it's a bunch of very inconsistantly named files, though all prefixed with numbers, periods, spaces, and dashes.  I can't be more specific because it's so chaotic of input.  (As I said though, the regex I have is matching all the cases, removing or simplifying anything redundant is my goal if it's possible).

Answer (score 1):

This regex matches all of your sample inputs:

```
"\d+\.?\d*( -)? "
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/xgSdukWOMN).

Comment: It does match all the prefixes, but unfortunately it fails (by matching) on one of the actual files which has a name after the prefix which starts with a number.  I'm going to keep at it to see if I can find any pattern that isn't broken with these files (That or get the people who sent me the data itself to normalize the filenames)

Comment: @Trei add examples of input that should *not* match to your question

Comment: I think I found one that appears to work for all of it

`^\d+\.?(?:\d{2}(?!\d))?(?:[ -]*)?`

Example input btw would be "01.5 Million" ("5 Million" is the actual name) and "10 - 1000 Leagues" (Where "1000 Leagues") is the title.